# Concatenated Lists in Linq to Sql in a single query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, concatenation

I have this sql query (simplified for the example):

```
;WITH info as (
    --actually a complex multi table query, just simplified
    select UserID, RoleName
    from UserRole
),
AccountUsers as
(
    select distinct UserID
    from info
)
select UserID,
Roles = STUFF(
(
  SELECT ', ' + l.RoleName 
    FROM info AS l
    WHERE l.UserID = au.UserID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
from AccountUsers au
```

Is it possible to convert this into linq-to-sql so that it generates a single query? I have over 500 users and probably around a dozen or so roles. It doesn't have to generate the same query, just the same results.(Built a demo of the sql here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c54fc/4 )

(edit: added linq)
This is the linq I have that is generating multiple queries:

```
var userroles = dc.UserRoles
    .Select(ua => new
    {
        ua.UserID,
        Roles = string.Join(", ", 
            dc.UserRoles
                .Where(ur => ur.UserID == ua.UserID )
                .Select(ur => ur.RoleName)
                .Distinct())
    });
```

Comment: Why not just make it a stored procedure instead?  Not sure about Linq-to-sql, but I know EF will turn stored procedures into method calls on the context.

Comment: That is my backup plan @juharr, but if it's possible in linq, I'd like to learn so I can compare results

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't know if this will work for Linq to SQL, but this is how you might do it with a list of classes:

```
var groupedUserRoles = userRoles
    .GroupBy(ur => ur.UserID)
    .Select(ur => new
        {
            UserId = ur.Key,
            Roles = ur.Select(r => r.RoleName)
        })
    .ToList();

groupedUserRoles.ForEach(ur => 
    Console.WriteLine($"UserID: {ur.UserId}, Roles: {string.Join(", ", ur.Roles)}"));
```

**Output**

[image]